# testing none-free items from itunesconnect in sandbox mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, app-store-connect

I am testing in app purcahsement by phonegap IAP plugin. the plugin works well and

I've done for testing free-subscribe items. However, I need to test none-free items too.

from manage in app purchases section on itunesconnect, I only can add free-subscribe items only.

there is no buttons for $0.99 or $1.99 but only a button for free-subscribe.

Is it possible to add none-free items from sandbox mode? how developers can be sure

their none-free items works in sandbox mode? is there no way to test none-free item before

submitting an app? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add free subscription items from iTunes Connect because you haven't sign the legal agreements and contracts for In-App Purchases.

From that page:

> If a type is missing, make sure you have agreed to all recent contracts. The Legal user must go to the ["Contracts, Tax, and Banking"](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/8.0.0.9.9.3.1.1.1.13.1.1.11.1.1) module on iTunes Connect to agree to the latest Paid Applications agreement. You must agree to the [Developer Program License Agreement](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements) before you can access the Paid Applications agreement.

Your account must me the Agent.